# Strange MEDIA_ROOT location

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I'm using wysiwyg redactor for admin page. So I can add some images to my articles. Firstly, In `settings.py`I wrote:

```
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = '/media/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in this case, all uploaded images are in `C:\media\uploads`. It's working.

But I need images to be located in project folder. So I write:

```
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = os.path.abspath('/media/uploads/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then image location: src="/media/C%3A/virtenvs/web/src/mysite/media/uploads/CAM00415.jpg"
But when debugging settings.py, `MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:\\virtenvs\\web\\src\\mysite\\media'`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You put a relative path in `MEDIA_ROOT` and an absolute path in `REDACTOR_UPLOAD`. Compare the following two in an interactive console:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('media/')
C:\\Users\\<username>\\media
>>> os.path.abspath('/media/')
C:\\media
```

`C:\Users\<username>` is the current working directory here. Unless you use an absolute path (starting with a `/`), the path in `abspath` will get appended to your current directory. The working directory of django seems to be `C:\virtenvs\web\src\mysite`, which also appears to be your project's directory, so in this case using a relative path for both settings should work:

```
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = os.path.abspath('media/uploads/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('media/')
```

Comment: I did as you said, but the path in img is wrong: <img src=/media/C%3A/virtenvs/web/src/mysite/media/uploads/%D0%9B%D0%B8_vFzFI3v.jpg>

Comment: why media is the first folder in 'src'? Maybe it's because of wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 0):

[MEDIA_ROOT must be an absolute filesystem path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#media-root), example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C://media/'
```

to make it inside project folder:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')
```